# I am getting null pointer exception below

Tags: java, android, webview

I hope you are doing great I am developing news where I have used WebView for Detailactivity but I am getting following null pointer exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.worldnews/yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.worldnews.news.DetailActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()'

on a null object reference when I click article items want to start DetailActivity.

**below my DetailActivity.java where I have implemented webview.**

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class DetailActivity extends Activity{


    public Article article;
    @BindView(R.id.article)
    WebView article_webview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);
        article_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        article_webview.loadUrl(article.getUrl());





    }
    public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

below my detail_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Your `article_webview` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ButterKnife.bind(this);` line after `setContentView()`

Comment: Thanks          it is working

Comment: Happy Coding...!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `ButterKnife.bind(this);` to bind your `views`.
Call this after `setContentView(<layout-id>)`;